# vbscript IE click on link in nav bar

Tags: html, vbscript

I need to click on a menu item in a nav bar that does not have any id or name that I can see.

I tried clicking on the specific element but I get the error "object required".

```
 ie.document.getElementById("toc_20003").Click
```

So I tried getting a collection of links or objects so I could see what my options were but nothing is displayed.

```
 set oelm=ie.document.getelementsbyname("mainMenu")
 for each elm in oelm
      wscript.echo elm.id
 next
```

I also tried the above with ie.document.links(1) but nothing is displayed.

Here is the html. The link I want is at the end "All Titles":

`<div id="navBarContainer"><div id="navBar"><ul id="mainMenu"><li id="toc_10000" class="CurrentSection CurrentPage Leaf"><a href="page.aspx?location=HOME&cache=10062000346">Home</a></li><li id="toc_20000" class="Open"><a href="javascript:;" onfocus="blur()" onclick="mainMenuClick('toc_20000', '')" title="Explore aggregate and per-title sales data for your titles and your competitors' titles.">Sales Reports</a><ul><li id="toc_20003" class="Leaf"><a href="puballeypage.aspx?location=ALLSRCH&cache=10062000346" title="Sales for individual titles or groups of titles.  Compare your sales with competitors' sales.">All Titles</a></li>`

How do I click this? Also, the web page has just been repainted after the vbscript has logged onto the website. Do I need to do something to force the new page elements to be available?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
' Get all links...
Set a = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")

' Find the link titled "All Titles" and click it...
For i = 0 To a.Length - 1
    If a(i).innerText = "All Titles" Then a(i).Click
Next
```

Comment: Thanks you. I tried your method and nothing happened. So I added  wscript.echo a.length after the set. It displayed length as 0 so there are no tagname("a") on that document. That's why I wondered if I need to force the new page to be available if that makes sense. Load it somehow?

Comment: Are you waiting/sleeping for the page to be completely loaded?

Comment: I think so. Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub

Comment: I added code to see document.all and the collection has only tagnames HTML, HEAD, and BODY. Trying now to see names and ids in document.all collection.

Comment: OK. I would change your code to `Loop While IE.ReadyState <> 4 OR IE.Busy`. Don't continue while either one is true.

Comment: Changed it, but it had no effect.

Comment: Let me fool with this a little, I just got some output that might have come from your change to the wait. I will let you know.

Comment: A few tests ago, I got over 300 items in the document.all collection, but each time I run now, I get HTML, HEAD, and BODY only. I did not change the code. So I added wscript.sleep 7000 before running your code to give it ALOT of time. Didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: I guess I don't know. Tough to know for certain from my standpoint. What changed between the test where you got 300 items and the following test where you didn't?

Comment: My inconsistent tag results have something to do with caching, I  think. I changed my script to navigate directly to the page I wanted after login, instead of clicking to it. Then used your code to find the innertext. This seems to offer consistent results. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear you figured it out.